# How can i add edit profile link dynamically?

Tags: 7

I have change the default user account page url to cms/dashboard and its redirect to custom page where edit profile link is not available. So i want to add the custom edit link, i add the block image and add the link to that image which is cms/[account:uid]/edit but its converting like cms/%5Baccount%3Auid%5D/edit. Is there any other way to add the Edit Profile link so that user can access the default edit page and change the profile information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the link directly as `/user`. It goes to the profile page which is similar to the /user/{$GLOBALS['user']->uid}

OR

Use [Token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token)  to create a menu link with this path: `user/[current-user:uid]/edit`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Me Alias" module which you can use this. Like if you want a edit profile link then simply pass the reference user/me/edit.